# адаптер RecyclerView возвращает позицию -1

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, kotlin

Есть метод, в котором обрабатываю нажатие по элементу:

```
override fun onListItemClick(itemIndex: Int, itemCode: String) {
    presenter.onItemClick(adapter.getItem(itemIndex))
}
```

Но проблема в том, что пользователь как то умудрился нажать на -1 элемент. Что выдало мне ошибку:

> "backtrace" => "[\"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length\u003d25; index\u003d-1\",\" at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)\",\" at com.project.android.features.common.base_list.AbstractListAdapter.getItem(AbstractListAdapter.kt:20)\",\" at com.project.android.features.categories.selector.CategorySelectDialog.onListItemClick(CategorySelectDialog.kt:59)\",\" at com.project.android.features.categories.selector.CategorySelectItemViewHolder$1.onClick(CategorySelectItemViewHolder.kt:32)\",\" at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)\",\" at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)\",\" at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)\",\" at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)\",\" at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)\",\" at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)\",\" at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)\",\" at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)\",\" at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)\",\" at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)\"]",

Как такое возможно? И как исключить момент нажатия пользователя на -1 элементе списка?

В одном из мест где использую данный метод:

```
        titleView.setOnClickListener { listener?.onListItemClick(adapterPosition, "") }
```

Перешёл к реализации adapterPosition и увидел следующее:

> /**
>            * Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder.
>            *
>
> * Note that this might be different than the {@link #getLayoutPosition()} if there are
>            * pending adapter updates but a new layout pass has not happened yet.
>            *
>
> * RecyclerView does not handle any adapter updates until the next layout traversal. This
>            * may create temporary inconsistencies between what user sees on the screen and what
>            * adapter contents have. This inconsistency is not important since it will be less than
>            * 16ms but it might be a problem if you want to use ViewHolder position to access the
>            * adapter. Sometimes, you may need to get the exact adapter position to do
>            * some actions in response to user events. In that case, you should use this method which
>            * will calculate the Adapter position of the ViewHolder.
>            *
>
> * Note that if you've called {@link RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()}, until the
>            * next layout pass, the return value of this method will be {@link #NO_POSITION}.
>            *
>            * @return The adapter position of the item if it still exists in the adapter.
>            * {@link RecyclerView#NO_POSITION} if item has been removed from the adapter,
>            * {@link RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()} has been called after the last
>            * layout pass or the ViewHolder has already been recycled.
>            */

Возможно где то тут кроется проблема? Так как именно в этом методе возвращается -1.

```
public final int getAdapterPosition() {
        if (mOwnerRecyclerView == null) {
            return NO_POSITION;
        }
        return mOwnerRecyclerView.getAdapterPositionFor(this);
    }
```

Comment: Исключить, ну например так: `if (itemIndex < 0) return;`. А чтобы понять как так получилось надо смотреть код, который вызывает `onListItemClick`.

Comment: А может ли быть, что -1 индекс это последний элемент списка (-2 предпоследний и т.д.)? :)

Comment: @gil9red а вот не знаю если честно. А как я могу это посмотреть?

Comment: Без кода, который связан с проблемой (получение индекса) никто вам ничего вразумительного не ответит. Код в вопросе не связан напрямую с проблемой, а является ее следствием (полученный индекс выходит за пределы диапазона)

Comment: @pavlofff тогда стоит также показать код где данный метод используется?

Comment: Такое чувство что вы где то сделали -1. Попробуйте посмотреть что будет если нажать на последний элемент

Comment: @Flippy всё работает корректно, я не знаю как пользователь умудрился прокликать по данному элементу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При получении позиции в списке адаптера через метод `getAdapterPosition()`, возможны ситуации, когда адаптер `RecyclerView` возвращает значение [NO_POSITION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#NO_POSITION) (значение константы -1), например, когда клик по айтему произошел во время обновления списка. Такую ситуацию нужно обрабатывать отдельно, например так (совершать действия по клику на айтеме только когда позиция не равна NO_POSITION):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.menu_button:
                //
                break;
            case R.id.card:
               //
                break;
      }
   }
}
```

или использовать метод `getLayoutPosition()`, который тоже имеет свои недостатки (позиция не всегда соответствует действительной при определенных обстоятельствах).

Подробнее [смотрите офф.документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) (раздел Positions in RecyclerView)

Comment: звучит очень логично, но загвоздка в том, как я могу проверить что всё работает как надо? Ну то есть да, из кода видно что элемент не должен быть -1, но разве этого достаточно?

Comment: @Inkognito да, достаточно. при no_position просто ничего не будет происходить. Оттестить довольно проблемно ввиду специфики  проявления, но при использовании такого решения ни одного падения по индексу -1мной замечено не было.

Comment: Хорошо, последний уточняющий вопрос, в holdere получается реализовать без проблем, но что если я хочу реализовать данное условие в самом методе onListItemClick, как я могу обратиться к getAdapterPosition()?

Comment: @Inkognito крайне не рекомендуется возвращать из адаптера невалидную позицию, а потом пытаться это обойти, единственное, что можно так получить - большее количество кода на проверки, которых можно избежать. Если сильно хочется, то вам не надо обращаться в колбэке к самому методу getAdapterPosition() - в адаптере он вернет -1, вы получите это значение через колбэк и боритесь с ним, как вам нравится (то, что у вас есть и сейчас, судя по всему).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы до выявления проблемы, посоветовал бы обернуть метод в try-catch:

```
override fun onListItemClick(itemIndex: Int, itemCode: String) {
    try {
        presenter.onItemClick(adapter.getItem(itemIndex))
    } catch (e: Exception) { }
}
```

- Вообще в блок catch неплохо бы выводить логи об ошибке, что то вроде:

  e.log()

А уже в нём реализуете метод получения ошибки(примерно как то так).

Comment: ну я так понимаю это равносильно записи if (itemIndex < 0) return только дополнительно с выводом ошибки? А можно поподробней о выводе ошибке.

Comment: Именно. По поводу метода, который будет выводить ошибку, стоит лучше задать новый вопрос я думаю.

Comment: Стектрейс полный не пишите никогда хватит и самого описания ошибки, которое можно получить с помощью `e.log()`.

Comment: @Flippy не совсем понял Ваш комментарий) что конкретно вы хотели сказать?)

Comment: @Flippy никогда хватит? типо достаточно будет дефолтного метода? или я не правильно понял?